# Silverlight WebClient class returning empty string

Tags: silverlight, facebook, silverlight-4.0, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to make a basic 'Silverlight Class Library' in Silverlight 4 to return basic Facebook Information using Facebook's Graph API, but I am only getting empty strings being returned. 
I am using the following code:

```
string _Response = "";

    public string GetFacebookMe(string access_token)
    {
        WebClient facebookClient = new WebClient();
        facebookClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(facebookClientDownloadStringCompleted);
        facebookClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me" + "?access_token=" + access_token));
        string ret = _Response;

        return ret;
    }

    private void facebookClientDownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            _Response = e.Result;
        }
        else
        {
            _Response = e.Error.Message;
        }
    }
```

I tried while debugging to init _Response to the value "Default", and the string "Default" was consequently being returned. I have been messing with this for a while and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It means a lot of effort to use directly WebClient. When using Silverlight and .Net Framework 4.0 you may use [Facebook C# SDK at Codeplex](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

[Usage of the SDK is excellently covered in this blog by Prabir Shrestha](http://blog.prabir.me/post/Facebook-CSharp-SDK-What%E2%80%99s-new-in-v5-3.aspx)

Comment: I don't know how that guy is getting his code working. I just downloaded SDK 5.3 (The latest, BETA copy, that he uses in his latest post), and there are several issues with it. The "async" infront of his function name is not recognised, the "await" command infront of the FacebookClient Get is not recognised, and there is no function called GetTaskAsync, I only have GetAsync.

Comment: Sorry, some of my issues are because im not using AsyncCtpLibrary.dll, but I dont seem to have it. Just searched my C drive and it doesn't exist ;/

Comment: Ok I've installed it, and implemented it as it says. But I'm getting an "Unhandled Exception"- [net_unknown_prefix] - on line var task = client.GetTaskAsync("4");